# R DT datatable - format text field and vertically align another field

Tags: jquery, html, r, datatable, shiny

I have a dataset with a text field which I would like to display using the function `datatable` from the package `DT`. I would also like to **(1)** format that text field so that the line breaks are displayed and emphasis is placed on certain chunks of text; and **(2)** vertically align the remaining fields so that their values are pushed to the top.

Consider the below example:

```
library(DT)
L <- 10
datatable(
  data.frame(
    var1 = sapply(1:L, function(x) 
      paste("<X>",paste0(x,
                         letters, 
                         LETTERS, 
                         "\n", 
                         collapse=" "))),
    var2 = round(rnorm(L),2)
  ) 
)
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, the output ignores `\n`. I would also like to make `<X>` bold. I've tried using HTML tags such as `<br>` but nothing seems to work as the text inside `var1` is escaped. Unescaping it (which can be achieved via `datatable` options) is not a good idea as the (actual) text contains special characters. I would also like the values of `var2` to be pushed to the top.

Just in case it make a difference, I would like to use the outputs in a Shiny web-app.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the line break in the DT cells you need to use `<br/>` instead of \n and escape(it will be read as HTML) the column with the escape argument.

To change the alignment of a value in a cell you can use the columnDefs argument within the options of datatable function. The problem is that you only can align horizontal.( left, right and center)
With the rowCallback function I can manually set every value in the second column to top alignment. But this is not an ideal solution.

```
library(DT)
L <- 10

dataset <- data.frame(
  var1 = sapply(1:L, function(x) 
    paste("<X>",paste0(x,
                       letters, 
                       LETTERS, 
                       "<br/>", 
                       collapse=" "))),
  var2 = round(rnorm(L),2)
)

datatable(dataset, escape = 1,  
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 2)),
    rowCallback=JS(paste0("function(row, dataset) {var value=dataset[2]; if (value!==null) $(this.api().cell(row,2).node()).css({'vertical-align': 'text-top'});}"))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To **vertically align** your column content you can do this:

```
T1 <- datatable(dataset)

 T1 %>%
  formatStyle(c('column_1','column_2'), 'vertical-align'='top') %>% 
  formatStyle(c('column_1','column_2'), 'text-align' = 'left')
```