# R DT datatable - hide or format filter pane

Tags: jquery, css, r, datatable, shiny

Consider the following example:

```
library(DT)
L <- 10
datatable(
  data.frame(
    var1 = sapply(1:L, function(x) 
      paste("<X>",paste0(x,
                         letters, 
                         LETTERS, 
                         "\n", 
                         collapse=" "))),
    var2 = round(rnorm(L),2)
  ) 
)
```

And here is the output:

[image: output]

I would like to either hide or format (change the background colour and the font family) the top part of the output that contains "Show X entries" together with the "Search" tab. I've found ways out formatting the rows and the headers by injecting CSS and JS code into the `options` of `datatable` and using the `formatStyle` function, but I can't find a way of dealing with the filter pane.

Just in case it makes any difference, I intend to use the outputs in a Shiny web-app.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you go to section 2.5 of this page: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: You can design your own custom table container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dom argument you can select with parts of the datatable you want to show and in which order.

More info here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

With the style argument you can change the style of the whole datatable by using the style argument. You can choose between: "default", "bootstrap", "bootstrap4", "foundation", "jqueryui", "material", "semanticui", "uikit".

More info here: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/

```
library(DT)
L <- 10

dataset <- data.frame(
    var1 = sapply(1:L, function(x) 
      paste("<X>",paste0(x,
                         letters, 
                         LETTERS, 
                         "\n", 
                         collapse=" "))),
    var2 = round(rnorm(L),2)
  )

  datatable(dataset, style = 'bootstrap', options = list(
    dom = 't')
)
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that did it! I'd appreciate if you could also look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348629/r-dt-datatable-format-text-field-and-vertically-align-another-field , perhaps you might know how to solve it. Cheers